# Problem Exporting rotated MaTeX with a transparency

Tags: export, rotation, opacity, matex

I'm trying to save an Graphics with rotated MaTeX and a transparency. My code is below.

```
g = Show[
  Graphics[Inset[MaTeX["AAAAA", Magnification -> 4]]], 
  Graphics[Rotate[Inset[MaTeX["AAAAA", Magnification -> 4]], π/4]]]
Export["Rotated.png", g, Background -> None];
```

When you run this code, you'll notice that the horizontal TeX is in the exported image, but the rotated is not.

Comment: It works fine in version 11.2.  It might be a bug in an earlier version.

Comment: I've got 11.1. I'll try to upgrade tonight and will report.

Comment: It might be good to mention your operating system too. It could be OS-dependent instead of version-dependent.

Comment: Still seeing the bug in 11.2. MacOS 10.13.1

Comment: Strange. I get [the expected output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7o1k3xjw0dz2cmj/Rotated.png?dl=0) with M11.2 on macOS 10.13.1.

Comment: I'm using "pdfLaTeX" -> "/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex". Could that be the reason?

Comment: I do not think this problem is related to MaTeX in any way. MaTeX just outputs a Graphics object. I suggest you include this Graphics in your question in InputForm so people who don't have MaTeX can try to reproduce the problem. For example, take the output of `MaTeX["\\square"]`, which is short enough to include in full.

Comment: Can you please post the Graphics output and show a MaTeX-independent minimal example?  As I said, I cannot reproduce this, but I am interested in *when* this failure occurs.